# I am currently working on a budget application in Django in which information is updated and saved through the handsontable spreadsheet

Tags: python, django, pycharm, handsontable

I created view function to save the data from handsontable but it keeps rendering the following error and I cannot find where the error is:

```
Data to be sent: (4) [Array(10), Array(10), Array(10), Array(10)]0: (10) ['123', 'Office Expeses', 'Expenses', 1, 6, 7, 12, 13, 18, 57]1: (10) ['134', 'Other Expenses', 'Expenses', 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 57]2: (10) ['144', 'Office Supplies', 'Expenses', 3, 4, 9, 10, 15, 16, 57]3: (10) ['Column Total', '', '', 6, 15, 24, 33, 42, 51, 171]length: 4[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
(index):243     POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/budgets/budgets/spreadsheet_view/23456/save_planning/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @ (index):243
(index):253 Network response was not ok. Status: 500 Internal Server Error
(anonymous) @ (index):253
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):251
(index):263 Fetch error: Error: Network response was not ok
    at (index):254:19
(anonymous) @ (index):263
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):262
(index):264 Error saving data: Error: Network response was not ok
    at (index):254:19
(anonymous) @ (index):264
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):262
```

I created the following view function:

def save_planning(request, budget_code):
print("Received POST request:", request.POST)

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        print("Received Data:", data)  # Debug statement
        budget = Budget.objects.get(budget_code=budget_code)
        print("Budget:", budget)  # Debug statement

        for item in data:
            print("Processing Item:", item)  # Debug statement
            planning, created = Planning.objects.get_or_create(budget=budget)
            planning.contract_name = item[2]  
            planning.contract_value = item[3]  
            planning.start_date = item[4]  
            planning.end_date = item[5]  
            planning.contract_number = item[6]  
            planning.save()

            # Update MonthlyValue instances
            for monthly_value in item[6:10]:  
                month = monthly_value[0]  
                value = monthly_value[1]  
                MonthlyValue.objects.update_or_create(planning=planning, month=month, defaults={'value': value})

        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Data saved successfully!'})

    except Exception as e:
        # Print or log the exception for debugging
        print("Error:", e)
        # Return an error response with a specific error message if needed
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'An error occurred while saving data.'}, status=500)

# If the request method is not POST, return an error response
return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method.'}, status=400)
```